# Asterisk Web API to calculate Wait Times

Tags: asterisk, asp.net-web-api, pbx

I would like to know if there is a web api for asterisk. I would also like to know if the average wait time to talk to a customer service agent is exposed through the api.

I have looked around online, but could not get an firm answer.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, no, there is no such thing in Asterisk.

What does exist is the ability of parsing [the queue_log file](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/ACD_id289009.html). You can get the moment the call started, the moment the call was answered by an agent, and subtract them - this will give you the wait time. Also, the first extra data value of the CONNECT event contains the time waited.

(If you are not in the mood for parsing a text file, you can register the queue logs in the database and use SQL to generate reports based on the logs. This is in fact my preferred approach.)

If you want to provide this information to other apps, you can write your own application which reads queue_log file/table and provides a webservice which returns wait times. In the case you decide to do it, we can try some more robust answers.